# Subversion (SVNKit) working with Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have the following problem, working with Jenkins. I try to build the project and receive following mistake:

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/kobv-albert-commons/workspace
Checking out a fresh workspace because Jenkins failed to detect the current workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/kobv-albert-commons/workspace
ERROR: svn: The path '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/kobv-albert-commons' appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater
working copy rooted at '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins'.
Please upgrade your Subversion (SVNKit) client to use this working copy.
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: The path '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/kobv-albert-commons' appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater
working copy rooted at '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins'.
Please upgrade your Subversion (SVNKit) client to use this working copy.
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.checkWCNG(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:143)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.checkWCNG(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:145)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.checkWCNG(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:145)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.open(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:190)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.doOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:379)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:283)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.probeOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:310)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.probeOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:295)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.crawlEntries(SVNWCClient.java:3304)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2506)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2873)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.parseSvnInfo(UpdateUpdater.java:115)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.isUpdatable(UpdateUpdater.java:87)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:120)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:136)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:788)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:769)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:753)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:743)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:685)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1367)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:674)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:579)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: The path '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/kobv-albert-commons' appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater
working copy rooted at '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins'.
Please upgrade your Subversion (SVNKit) client to use this working copy.
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:181)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:133)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.checkWCNG(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:138)
    ... 29 more
```

I don't use Eclipse, Idea or some other tool. I tried following commands: svn upgrade and svn update, But it doesn't help. I use Jenkins Subversion Plugin 1.5

Answer (score 6):

If you go into the *Manager Jenkins* menu, and into the *Configure System* page, you should see a **Subversion** section. This section allows you to adjust your Working Copy format. There was a big change in the Subversion working copy format from version 1.6 to 1.7. Apparently, something you did created a Subversion 1.6 version of the working copy. Change the SVNKit plugin to version 1.6, and clean the workspace. (Go into the project, select *Workspace* from the left side, and then click on *Wipe out current workspace*). Then, try another build.

Jenkins doesn't use the installed Subversion command line client and doesn't even need it. Instead, it uses SVNKit to checkout and working directory. Your error is that it tried to do an update, but sees the wrong version:

```
ERROR: svn: The path '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/kobv-albert-commons' appears to \
   be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater working copy rooted at \
   '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins'.
```

Fortunately, SVNKit can emulate multiple versions of the Subversion client working directory, and Jenkins allows you to adjust SVNKit to the correct setting. I too have the 1.5 version of the Jenkins Subversion client plugin. It will do any client workspace format from 1.4 to 1.7.